# Exception : A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I try to add `Windows.Web.Http.dll` to my windows phone 8.1 application , in my visual studio 2013 environment, I am getting the following exception.

```
A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project
```

[image]

I don't see any "Unblock" options as many bloggers suggest.

If someone have come across such an error, please share your thoughts..
Thanks in advance

~Sebastian

Comment: I had a similar problem in an ASP.Net application. If it's the same architecture as I think, check the content of your web.config file, section "assemblies". It's maybe just a problem of older version specified in the web.config or a dll in the bin folder.

Comment: I don't have web.config file, as I am creating a windows phone application

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Browse panel but instead search in the Assemblies panel, the Windows.Web.Http.dll  you have seems to not support Windows Phone 8.1 project.

Answer (score 0):

Windows.Web.Http is **not supported in Windows Phone 8** Check the requirement section on below documentation link for Windows.Web.Http

[**Windows.Web.Http namespace**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.web.http)

For windows phone 8 try using `System.Net.WebClient`.

*P:S. I will recommend use Windows phone 8.1*

Hope this helps

Comment: I am using windows phone 8.1, by mistake , I had mentioned it as 8

Comment: Then this assembli is already included in Windows Phone 8.1 reference.

Comment: you need to add this using statment Windows.Web.Http and can use HttpClient

Comment: added this line  "using Windows.Web.Http;"
 but got an error - 
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) D:\Sample codes\TestPhoneApp1\TestPhoneApp1\MainPage.xaml.cs 12 15 TestPhoneApp1

Comment: can you check Target windows phone OS version the project properties to make sure you are using targeting windows phone 8.1? as this works perfect in both Windows phone 8.1 RT and windows phone 8.1 silverlight

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake...
It is phone 8.0; I thought it would be 8.1.. How I can upgrade it to 8.1?

Comment: What... it was windows phone 8 :). no problem it happens. But I think it is pretty much clear now :)

Comment: @SebastianXavier Right-click on your Windows Phone 8 project, you should see something like "Upgrade to Windows Phone 8.1". But I thinks that will do a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project, and I don't know if you want to create a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight or a Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT / Universal App).